# Swift Spritekit. How am I able to lock a node in a particular point?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to figure out how to lock a `SKSpriteNode` in a particular y point. When my finger touches on the screen, the node displayed on the point where I touched. This is because inside `TouchesBegan` method, I wrote lines of code which are:

```
if isMovable == false {
  isMovable = true
  for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    ship.position = location
  }
}
```

And then, I wrote these lines of code instead in order to get only the x point:

```
for touch in touches {
  let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
  ship.position = CGPointMake(location, self.frame.height/2 - 200)
}
```

However, the result I got was that location is not usable there because it is `CGPoint`, not `CGFloat`. I tried to cast it as `CGFloat(location)`, but futile. Is there any way to lock a node in a y point?

The desirable function I want is when I touch anywhere on the screen, a y point is locked, meaning that a node is only movable horizontally, but not vertically movable.

Since my English is not good enough, I may lack missing some explanation that enables you guys to understand my problem more clearly. I appreciate if you understand me, and give me the solution! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `location` variable is of type `CGPoint` which is :

> A structure that contains a point in a two-dimensional coordinate system.
>   [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGPoint)

So you could use that same variable `location` to get the `x`position and lock the `y`to whatever point you choose:

```
for touch in touches {
   let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
   ship.position = CGPointMake(location.x, self.frame.height/2 - 200)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and well it worked. However, this is not what I was looking for. After I tapped the screen, a node is placed exactly in a x point and y point as they were programmed. The problem is that after a second touch, the node moves and it does not remain where it first appeared. I want that node to be there forever while the system is running. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: @ryohei Well you have a couple of solutions. One of them is to generate sprites directly in you `touchesBegan` method. You create your sprite, then assign its position to your touch location.